# Dual LGA 1366 Motherboard won't POST

Tags: cpu, motherboard

On a Intel S5520HCT Dual Socket LGA 1366 motherboard I replaced the CPU's with higher spec'd Xeon E5649's. The board would not POST. When using just one CPU I can boot with no problems. I tried both of the new CPU's in socket one and it boots up fine, so the issue is not a faulty processor.

The next thing I tried was to revert to my old CPU's, but it would no longer boot with 2 installed.

This made me think I may have damaged the pins on socket two when removing the old CPU's. I have spent some hours inspecting the socket and cleaning it with alcohol but cannot see any problems.

So I am left scratching my head. I have put the server back in service with just one of the new CPU's installed and am trying to theorize a solution.

My questions:

1. Is it possible the damage is on the active socket (socket one) and that is causing socket two not to work? I haven't inspected that socket yet as I didn't think of this possibility until I put it back in production.
2. Any other thoughts?

Other things I have cleared:
- Power Supply and connectors all OK
- Fans all working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, it is possible. Second QPI link is only used to connect to the other CPU so if pins related to that were damaged, it would work with one CPU but not with 2.

2) Check your CPU clamping pressure. Both too high and too low can cause some pins to not make adequate contact.

Comment: You were right. Socket 1 had 2 pins (or lands) bent a full 180 degrees. I have no idea how that happened. I managed to bend them back but it didn't restore my socket 2 sadly. The damage was done.